# Javascript button onclick event to call function inside function in module

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm drawing and coloring lines based on data with D3.js and want to update their colors when clicking a button. **My question is: how can I call `colorP1()` and `colorP2()`, declared in function `drawLines` in `drawLines.js`, from the `onclick` event of one of the buttons in `index.html`?**

I have tried:

1. using the `window.drawLines = drawLines` trick and have the onclick event refer to `window.drawLines.colorP2()`, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: colorP2 is not a function`
2. using `window.colorP2 = colorP2`, but I don't know how the import would work in this case

Any ideas to enlighten the mind of this humble beginner? As I understand it, `colorP1()` and `colorP2()` have to stay inside `drawLines()` because they need the `data` and `lines` variables from `drawLines()`--feel free to prove me wrong here.

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.line {
    stroke-width: 4px;
    fill: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import {drawLines} from './drawLines.js';

  d3.json("test.geojson").then(drawLines);
</script>

<body>
    <svg id='map'></svg>
    <button onclick="colorP1()">colorP1</button>
    <button onclick="colorP2()">colorP2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

drawLines.js

```js
function colorInterpolate(data, property) {
    let max_d = d3.max(data.features.map(d => d.properties[property]));
    let range = [max_d, 1];
    return d3.scaleSequential().domain(range).interpolator(d3.interpolateViridis); 
}

export function drawLines(data) {

    let width = 900,
        height = 500,
        initialScale = 1 << 23,
        initialCenter = [-74.200698022608137, 40.034504451003734]

    let svg = d3.select('#map')
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('width', width)

    let projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(initialScale)
        .center(initialCenter)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

    let path = d3.geoPath(projection)

    let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p1');

    let lines = svg.append('g')

    lines.selectAll('path')
        .data(data.features)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {
                return myColor(d.properties.p1);
            })

    function colorP2() {
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p2');
        lines.selectAll('path')
            .attr("stroke", d => myColor(d.properties.p2))
    }

    function colorP1() {
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p1');
        lines.selectAll('path')
            .attr("stroke", d => myColor(d.properties.p1))
    }
}
```

test.geojson

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "lines",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "p1": 1, "p2": 3}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -74.201304101157845, 40.033790926216739 ], [ -74.201226425025339, 40.033761910802717 ], [ -74.201164135201353, 40.033738641825124 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "p1": 2, "p2": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -74.200521185229846, 40.034804885753857 ], [ -74.200535458528648, 40.034780636493231 ], [ -74.200698022608137, 40.034504451003734 ], [ -74.200932444446437, 40.034106179618831 ], [ -74.201017665586349, 40.033961391736824 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong:

> As I understand it, colorP1() and colorP2() have to stay inside drawLines() because they need the data and lines variables from drawLines()

D3 binds data to the elements entered with `.data(data).join()` or `.data(data).enter()`. The datum is attached to the node. When using  `.attr("something",function(d) {` the `d` refers to the bound datum, not the original data array. So, you don't need the original data array, it is part of the DOM element.

Also, you don't need `lines` because you can remake that selection: `d3.selectAll("paths")` or `d3.selectAll(".line")`.

So, you can move the p1/p2 functions outside of your drawLines function.

As I wanted to simplify for the snippet below, I've got a function that is passed data to draw some circles. I then assign event listeners to the buttons (I could also use `onclick=""` attributes on the buttons directly) with D3 to call functions that recolor the circles:

```
function color1() {
 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .attr("fill",d=>d.color1);
}
```

The function access the bound datum and a given property (`d=>d.color1`) and by using `d3.selectAll()` we can select all the circles that exist at the time of the click:

```js
function draw(data) {
   var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", 300)
     .attr("height", 200);
     
   svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx",d=>d.x)
     .attr("cy",d=>d.y)
     .attr("fill",d=>d.color2)
     .attr("r", 20);
     
  
}

draw([{x: 100,y:50, color1: "steelblue",color2:"crimson"},{x:200,y:50,color1:"steelblue",color2:"crimson"}])

d3.selectAll("button")
  .data([0,1])
  .on("click", function(event,d) {
    if (d) color2();
    else color1();
  })
  
function color1() {
 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .attr("fill",d=>d.color1);
}
function color2() {
  d3.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("fill",d=>d.color2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button> Blue </button>
<button> Red </button>
</div>
```

*If you need the data array itself, you can extract that with `d3.selectAll("elements").data()`*

Of course, we could also append the buttons in your drawLines function, which would potentially make a cleaner outcome, especially if the buttons are dependent on the data in any form. This way if you ever wanted to change the buttons or the functions, everything is in one place, for example:

```js
var geojson = { "type": "FeatureCollection","name": "lines","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "p1": 1, "p2": 3}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -74.201304101157845, 40.033790926216739 ], [ -74.201226425025339, 40.033761910802717 ], [ -74.201164135201353, 40.033738641825124 ] ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "p1": 2, "p2": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -74.200521185229846, 40.034804885753857 ], [ -74.200535458528648, 40.034780636493231 ], [ -74.200698022608137, 40.034504451003734 ], [ -74.200932444446437, 40.034106179618831 ], [ -74.201017665586349, 40.033961391736824 ] ] } }]};

function drawLines(data) {

    let width = 500,
        height = 400,
        initialScale = 1 << 23,
        initialCenter = [-74.200698022608137, 40.034504451003734]

    let svg = d3.select('#map')
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('width', width)

    let projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .fitSize([width,height],data)

    let path = d3.geoPath(projection)

    let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p1');

    let lines = svg.append('g')

    lines.selectAll('path')
        .data(data.features)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', path)
        
    colorBy("p1");

    function colorBy(property) {
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(property);
        lines.selectAll('path')
            .attr("stroke", d => myColor(d.properties[property]))
    }
    
    function colorInterpolate(property) {
       let max_d = d3.max(data.features.map(d => d.properties[property]));
       let range = [max_d, 1];
       return d3.scaleSequential().domain(range).interpolator(d3.interpolateViridis); 
    }
    
    d3.selectAll(".property")
      .data(["p1","p2"])
      .enter()
      .append("button")
      .attr("class","property")
      .text(d=>d)
      .on("click", function(_,d) {
        colorBy(d);
      })
    .lower();
}

drawLines(geojson);
```

```css
.line {
    stroke-width: 4px;
    fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
 <svg id='map'></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks again, it's all clearer now. One follow-up question: given I need to normalize the color scheme by the data when I click my buttons (see line `let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p2');`), how would I go about doing this normalization without `data`? Would you suggest extracting it from the DOM itself?

Comment: @BernardoTrindade Updating the answer, but essentially you could use, you can recreate the data array with `d3.selectAll("elements").data()` to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can call like this to call inner functions:

```
<button onclick="(new drawLines().colorP1())">colorP1</button>
<button onclick="(new drawLines().colorP2())">colorP2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, the onclick event is now calling the function. The issue now is in drawLines.js, line 2, in that it `Cannot read property 'features' of undefined` because `data` is undefined. Given colorP2() is defined inside drawLines(), wasn't it supposed to have the value of `data`?

Comment: Yes, data will be undefined in this case because calling drawlines() everytime will invoke it creating a new instance. Your design seems to be incorrect in this case. One thing I can think of modifying the current code is initially store data in a global variable and use it everytime inside drawLines(). The correct way to implement in d3 is by selecting the id (selectAll) and using fill to change color. Now, color1() and color2() will not be inside drawLines() function.

Comment: I get it, this makes sense and the second option you mentioned sounds much cleaner. That said, how would you go about normalizing the colormap (`let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p2');`) without `data`? If at all possible, I would love to not have global variables.

Comment: You'll be calling drawLines() like this:
`d3.json("test.geojson").then((err, data) => drawLines(data));`
Now drawLines will have data. Now you can pass the data to `colorInterpolate` in the said line above

Answer (score 1):

**and work example for continue working...**

```js
var json1 ='{ "type" : "FeatureCollection", "name":"lines",  "crs": { "type": "name", "properties":{ "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }}, "features" : [{  "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "id" : 3, "p1" : 1, "p2": 3}, "geometry" : {"type" : "LineString","coordinates":[[ -74.201304101157845, 40.033790926216739],[-74.201226425025339,40.033761910802717 ],[-74.201164135201353,40.033738641825124]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties":{ "id" : 4, "p1" : 2, "p2" :2 },"geometry" : { "type": "LineString", "coordinates" : [[ -74.200521185229846, 40.034804885753857 ],[ -74.200535458528648, 40.034780636493231 ],[ -74.200698022608137, 40.034504451003734 ],[ -74.200932444446437, 40.034106179618831 ],[ -74.201017665586349, 40.033961391736824 ]]}}]}';

var width = 900,
        height = 500,
        initialScale = 1 << 23,
        initialCenter = [-74.198698022608137, 40.034504451003734]
        
var svg = d3.select('#map')
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('width', width);
var lines = svg.append('g');

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(initialScale)
        .center(initialCenter)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
var path = d3.geoPath(projection)

function colorInterpolate(data, property) {
    let max_d = d3
      .max(data.features.map(d => d.properties[property]));
    let range = [max_d, 1];    
    return d3.scaleSequential()
             .domain(range)
             .interpolator(d3.interpolateViridis); 
}

function drawLines(data) {
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p1');
        
        lines.selectAll('path')
        .data(data.features)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {
                return myColor(d.properties.p1);
                });
}

function colorP2(data){
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p2');
        lines.selectAll('path')
        .attr("stroke", d=>myColor(d.properties.p2));
}

function colorP1(data){
        let myColor = colorInterpolate(data, 'p1');
        lines.selectAll('path')
        .attr("stroke", d=>myColor(d.properties.p1));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.line {
    stroke-width: 4px;
    fill: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  //import {drawLines} from './drawLines.js';
  //d3.json("test.geojson").then(drawLines);
 drawLines(JSON.parse(json1));
</script>

<body>
    <svg id='map'></svg>
    <button onclick="colorP1(JSON.parse(json1))">colorP1</button>
    <button onclick="colorP2(JSON.parse(json1))">colorP2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I'm not sure I follow. Where would the javascript code be? Would I insert it in a new <script></script> tag?

Comment: yes, all code insert to <script></script> tag  or if code is big inserting only link in the tags, for examle: `<script src="/js/script1.js"></script>`